# Add new data in database using TypeOrm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am using in my NestJs application type-orm.
I have 2 entities:

1. User

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  gender: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Address, (address) => address.user)
  address: Address;
}
```

2. Address

```js
@Entity()
export class Address {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.address)
  user: User;
}
```

The idea is next: `Each user can have multiple addresses`, this is why i used `OneToMany`.

My `provider` looks like this:

```js
async add(): Promise < User > {
  try {
    const newPost = this.usersRepository.create({
      gender: 'm',
    });
    return await this.usersRepository.save(newPost);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

It works and in db, in the table `user` i  can add `gender: 'm'`. 
Issue: How to add in `add()` function and the `addresses`, because now i can add just the `user`. 
 Question: How to change the `add()` function to be able to add and `addresses`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to fix the User entity by making addresses as an Array of addresses,

```
    @Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  gender: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Address, (address) => address.user)
  address: Address[];
}
```

For your question, you can achieve adding the address by saving them first then bind them with the user:

```
   async add(): Promise < User > {
  try {
    let adresses:Array<Address> = [] ; array of type Address entity
 for(let adress of sourceOfyouAdressses) //sourceOfyouAdressses = the array of addresses you want add
   {
    let  adrs =  await this.adress Repository.save({city: adress.city }); // here you save you adress informations
    adresses.push(adrs ); 
   }
const newPost = this.usersRepository.create({
      gender: 'm',
      address:adresses
    });
    return await this.usersRepository.save(newPost);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907844/update-a-column-in-database-in-nodejs

Comment: Sure, thanks to accepting this answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210852/get-hidden-field-from-database-using-nestjs