# Update a column in database in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to update a column which has a relation:

```js
async update(req, res): Promise<any> {
        const {email, password, id} = req.body;
        try {
            await getConnection()
                .createQueryBuilder()
                .update(User)
                .set({
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    meta: [{   
                        name: "tesst",
                        message: "jasshd"
                    }]
                })
                .where("id = :id", {id: id})
                .execute();

            res.status(201).send({
                message: 'user updated'
            })

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('update', e)
            res.send({
                message: 'update error'
            })
        }
    }
```

Meta table is in relation with User table.
Trying to update the user with the attached meta i get: `EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "meta" was found.`. Why i get this error? Note: If i  use this relation when i register the user like:

```js
const user = this.usersRepository.create({
  email,
  password,
  meta: [{
    name: "tesst",
    message: "jasshd"
  }]
});
return await this.usersRepository.save(user);
```

... the code work. Why the code works when i register the user but not when i update it?

```css
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    email: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    password: string;


    @OneToMany(() => Meta, meta => meta.user, { cascade: true })
    meta: Meta[];
}


export class Meta {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: metaId})
    metaId: number;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    name: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    message: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.meta)
    user: User;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the meta & user entities to see which relation they have?

Comment: @Youba one to many

Comment: @Youba i updated the question with both entities. Could you help?

Comment: I don't think you can update the relation data from the user QueryBuilder, the solution is to create another meta QueryBuilder to update their data, I can provide an example of it you're positive with that solution

Comment: @Youba, it will be helpful. Could you show how to change my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can update the relation data with querybuilder, the solution I see here is to update `meta` with itself :

```
async update(req, res): Promise<any> {
    const {email, password, id} = req.body;
    try {
        await getConnection()
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .update(User)
            .set({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                meta: [{   
                    name: "tesst",
                    message: "jasshd"
                }]
            })
            .where("id = :id", {id: id})
            .execute();
  // Update meta :
    await getConnection()
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .update(Meta)
            .set({ 
                    name: "tesst",
                    message: "jasshd"
            })
            .where("user = :id", {id: id})
            .execute();
        res.status(201).send({
            message: 'user updated'
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('update', e)
        res.send({
            message: 'update error'
        })
    }
}
```

*Ps: this operation will update all the data of meta that has `user = :id`*

Comment: is that what you want?

Comment: i changed a lit a bit the entity `Meta` above. And where i update the Meta i added: `.where("userId = :userId", {userId: id})`, but it does not add any changes in meta table. Why?

Comment: You should use `user` not `userId `

Comment: one question, possible not related to this one. I have User entity and UserDataEntity. User has as relation UserDataEntity. In this way using `oneToMany`, in UserDataEntity si created a column like `userId`. Is there a posibilty to access a row from UserDataEntity according to userId? Because even if the userId column is created but i get an error that  `userId` column is not found. Could you help?

Comment: to access to user from UserDataEntity you should define the relation decorator for the userId

Comment: like this? const users = await this.userDataEntityRepository.findOne({
                where: {
                    userId: userId,
                },
                relations: ["userId"]
            });

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956555/delete-an-item-from-database-using-typeorm-in-nestjs