# Delete an item from Database using Typeorm in NestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have the `Users` entity: 
id|name  |age|images 
1 | John | 4 |  {123.jpg,258.png}

I want to delete an image from `images` column. According to [typeorm](https://typeorm.io/#/delete-query-builder/delete) documentation i can use:

```css
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .delete()
    .from(Users)
    .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .execute();
```

If use this i will delete the whole entity, but i need just to delete `123.jpg` from `images` column.

Question: How to delete `123.jpg` image from `images` column?
Note: I use NestJs and ProgresQl

Users entity:

```css
@Entity()
export class Users {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    ...

    @Column("text",{nullable: true, array: true})
    images: string[];
}
```

Comment: @AnushKamble, do you know a solution?

Comment: Are `images` just a colmun in User entity? please share The user entity

Comment: @Youba, i updated. Indeed the images is just a column. Is there a solution?

Comment: @AnushKamble, you can add your answer

Comment: @Youba, could you help?

Comment: you should just update the colmun, you don't need anything to do with delete in your case

Comment: @Youba, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967969/insert-data-in-database-depending-by-relation

Answer (score 0):

```
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .update()
    .set({ images: [...valuesWithoutThatImage] })
    .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .execute();
```

You need to update that object and set images to new desired value, in this case it should have all previous images without 123.jpg