# Get hidden field from database using NestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I applied hidden property on password:

```css
 @Column({nullable: true, select: false})
 password: string;
```

Doing the login i need the password filed. So according to he [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns)  i can select this hidden value by using:

```js
const qb = getConnection().createQueryBuilder()
const user = await qb
  .select("password", "password")
  .from(User, 'user')
  .where("password = :password", {
    password: password
  })
  .addSelect('password', 'password')
  .getOne()
```

Doing this i get `undefined` and the `password` property anyway remains hidden. 
How to get hidden values in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can select hidden value by using

```
.addSelect('user.password')
```

You have `.addSelect('password', 'password')` which will not work. Do not alias the columns for hidden columns. (Probably a bug in TypeOrm).

This will also work

```
   .select('user.password')
```

You don't need both `select` and `addSelect` for the same columns, the `addSelect` does nothing since the columns are already selected.

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537012/cant-filter-data-according-foreign-key-in-typeorm