# Can't filter data according foreign key in TypeOrm

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I use Nest Js, PostgresQl and Typeorm.
I  have these 2 entities in typeorm:

```js
export class Meta {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: "metaId"})
    metaId: number;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => TablesEntity, table => table.metaId, {eager: true, cascade: true})
    metaTables: TablesEntity[];
}
//
export class TablesEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Meta, meta => meta.metaTables)
    @JoinColumn({name: "metaId"})
    metaId: Meta;
}
```

And now i want to get all data according to a filtered value:

```js
const meta = await this.metaRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    metaId: metaId,
    metaTables: [{
        status: Not('white')
    }]
  },
  relations: ["metaTables"]
});
```

So i want to take all data that don't have the status: 'white', but i get an error: `No entity column "metaTables" was found`. 
 Why this error appear and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is there any chance, that you forgot to use the Entity decorator on the Meta class, so typeorm didn't generate table for it?

Comment: @Balint Csak, without `metaTables: [{
        status: Not('white')
    }]` i  get all data, so it works, but i need to filter the metaTables that does not have status white.

Comment: Maybe also a silly question, but is there any chance you forgot to add the status column to the TablesEntity?

Comment: @Asking thank you, this helped to make an answer for your question. Please give us a more accurate example later, because this was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, typeorm cannot handle nested queries within these methods (`findOne, findMany, update etc...`), what you've tried to use above. There are several different solutions however, but they all use a bit more complex approach.

The most similar solution is if you use the `find` method, but configure it with all the parameters of a query-builder:

```js
await connection.getRepository(Meta).findOne({
  where: (qb: SelectQueryBuilder<Meta>) => {
    qb.where({
      metaId: metaId,
    }).andWhere("metaTables.status != :status", { status: 'white' });
  },
  join: {
    alias: "meta",
    innerJoin: {
      metaTables: "meta.metaTables",
    },
  },
});
```

The other approach is if you simply use the query-builder and construct the following query:

```
await connection
  .getRepository(Meta)
  .createQueryBuilder("meta")
  .innerJoin("meta.metaTables", "metaTables")
  .where({ metaId: metaId })
  .andWhere("metaTables.status != :status", { status: "white" })
  .getOne();
```

There is a third solution however, but it works only `<=0.2.24`. This solution constructs the `where` object in that way, that each relation filter appears as a single string where the columns are concatenated with dots. Here is an example:

```
await connection.getRepository(Meta).findOne({
  where: {
    metaId: metaId,
    "metaTables.status": Not("white"),
  },
  relations: ["metaTables"],
});
```